# Dynamo = How to use LSI which has multiple # in it with DynamoDb.query using aws-sdk?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to query `Dynamo` using `aws-sdk`. I can query the with `Partition Key` with but when I try to add LSI, I am getting `ValidationException: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: begins_with, operand type: M` error and not sure how to fix it.

**Option-1:** This works

```
const res = await DynamoDb.query({
        TableName: tableName,

        ExclusiveStartKey: lastEvaluatedKey,
        KeyConditionExpression: 'tenantId = :tenantId',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':tenantId': tenantId
        }
    }).promise();
```

**Option-2:** Not sure what am I missing here.

```
const res = await DynamoDb.query({
        TableName: tableName,
        IndexName: 'index_channelOrderCreated_id_status',
        ExclusiveStartKey: lastEvaluatedKey,
        KeyConditionExpression: '#tenantId = :tenantId And begins_with(#orderCreatedDate, :orderCreatedDate)',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":tenantId": {
                "S": tenantId
            },
            ":orderCreatedDate": {
                "S": beginsWith
            }
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#tenantId": "tenantId",
            "#orderCreatedDate": "channelOrderCreated#id#status"
        }
    }).promise();
```

**Error:**

```
ValidationException: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: begins_with, operand type: M
```

**Table Structure:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dynamo DB isn't very smart, you need to pass in the `IndexName: 'STRING_VALUE',` property to tell it you want to use an LSI or GSI index.

SDK docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property)

Does your index have the same keys as the table?  There's no need for the index in that case.

I suspect the problem is your use of `ExclusiveStartKey: lastEvaluatedKey`

You don't want to include that in the initial call, only in subsequent calls; assuming you need more than one call to return all the data.  DDB will only read 1MB  of data at a time.

Comment: I forgot to add it here. Please see the updated question where I am also passing the index name. Still getting error around `begins_with`.

Comment: so I resolved this error by this change, `ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":tenantId": tenantId, ":orderCreatedDate": beginsWith  }`.My goal is to get data in specific range then delete it. This is first part, which is good now. In second part I am getting `validationexception the provided key element does not match the schema' error which I am trying to resolve now.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by following change:

```
const res = await DynamoDb.query({
        TableName: tableName,
        IndexName: 'index_channelOrderCreated_id_status',
        ExclusiveStartKey: lastEvaluatedKey,
        KeyConditionExpression:
            '#tenantId = :tenantId And begins_with(#orderCreatedDate, :orderCreatedDate)',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":tenantId": tenantId,
            ":orderCreatedDate": beginsWith,
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#tenantId": "tenantId",
            "#orderCreatedDate": "channelOrderCreated#id#status"
        }
    }).promise();
```